# How to arrange a non admin command as a systemd service?

Tags: linux, systemd

For example, I want to run `minikube start`.

First I created the following minikube.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs minikube on startup
After=vboxautostart-service.service vboxballoonctrl-service.service vboxdrv.service vboxweb-service.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/minikube start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I enabled it and on the next reboot the `systemd` framework attempted to run it. However, it failed because apparently the minikube start command is not supposed to run as root:

```
The "virtualbox" driver should not be used with root privileges.
```

How can I run it under a non admin user?

Comment: This should be a `oneshot`, not a `forking` type, with `RemainAfterExit=yes`, and should have an `ExecStop=` defined to stop minikube.

Comment: This is fantastic input. Could you answer here - https://serverfault.com/questions/1035376/how-to-run-minikube-start-as-a-linux-service-on-startup so I could credit you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define which user have to be used bu the service. For example:

```
[Unit]
...

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/minikube start
User=user1
Group=group1

...
```

Comment: Oh, I will try it now.

Comment: That worked! The command line still fails, but that would be a different question, because it fails for other reasons.